# Drawing straight line with spritekit and UITouch creates multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uitouch

Should be simple.

I'm trying to draw a single, straight line using UITouch and Spritekit. However, when touchesmoved is called, it creates multiple lines instead of just a single line. Code used is below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    positionInScene1 = [touch locationInNode:self];

    pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();

    selectorLine = [SKShapeNode node];
    selectorLine.strokeColor = [SKColor greenColor];
    selectorLine.lineWidth = 5;
    [self addChild:selectorLine];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    pathToDraw2 = CGPathCreateMutable();
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    positionInScene2 = [touch locationInNode:self];

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw2, NULL, positionInScene1.x, positionInScene1.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw2, NULL, positionInScene2.x, positionInScene2.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathToDraw);

    selectorLine.path = pathToDraw;
}
```

If I move

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene2.x, positionInScene2.y);
```

to touchesEnd, it creates a single line but only after the user ends the touch. I want the user to see the line being drawn as they touch.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: multiple lines from where to where? Additional lines each originating from the starting point to the current touch location, or additional lines between the previous and current touch location?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new path in your touchesMoved. You are modifying the same path, and just adding more and more lines to it.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!  Thanks Theis.  Hopefully the code above helps other newbie sprtiekit devs